# Black background color in app icon

Tags: codenameone

I've a app icon image in png(transparent) of size 512 * 512. It works well ie. transparent bg in android but in iOS the app has black background. How can I make it transparent in iOS?

[image]

Black bg in app icon...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the size of the icon is incorrect. Apple has very specific requirements about the shape of the icon as you can see from all the icons around: they all look the same.

The best approach for iOS is to create a completely square image which will be cut automatically to the right size.

Assuming you want this icon for Android and a different icon for iOS you can use this tip: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/different-icons.html

In the build.xml find

```
<target name="build-for-android-device" ... >
```

Change the line:

```
icon="androidIcon.png"
```

Then copy your existing icon to `androidIcon.png` and replace `icon.png` with a square icon.